# UITableViewSection footerTitle does not get localized

Tags: ios, uitableview, localization

I have added danish localization to my iOS 8 project. I want to localize the header and footer of a static `UITableViewSection`, the problem I'm facing is that the header gets localized, however the footer always has the string from the Main.strings (English) file. The values were set via Interface Builder. I've tested this both on device and simulator.

Main.strings (English)

```
/* Class = "UITableViewSection"; footerTitle = "..."; ObjectID = "cHU-BB-3aF"; */
"cHU-BB-3aF.footerTitle" = "Footer Title";

/* Class = "UITableViewSection"; headerTitle = "Payment Details"; ObjectID = "cHU-BB-3aF"; */
"cHU-BB-3aF.headerTitle" = "Header Title";
```

Main.strings (Danish)

```
/* Class = "UITableViewSection"; footerTitle = "..."; ObjectID = "cHU-BB-3aF";*/
"cHU-BB-3aF.footerTitle" = "Localized Footer Title"; // this does not work

/* Class = "UITableViewSection"; headerTitle = "Payment Details"; ObjectID = "cHU-BB-3aF"; */
"cHU-BB-3aF.headerTitle" = "Localized Header Title";  // this works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the footer's title in code and use an `NSLocalizedString` instead. To set the footer's title in code, you should implement `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`. So, it would look something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  let footerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
  footerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Your title for footer", comment: "Comment for footer")
  footerLabel.sizeToFit()
  return footerLabel
}
```

Then you can use the `genstrings` command in Terminal to create a Localizable.strings file:

1. Open Terminal and cd to the folder that contains your project
2. Type this command: `genstrings *.swift -o en.lproj`
3. Add the Localizable.strings file to your project

You can add a localization of the Localizable.strings file for Danish by selecting it in the Project navigator, selecting the File Inspector in Utilities, and then checking Danish.

Comment: the main issue was that my strings file was called Localization.strings instead of Localizable.strings